# Как правильно использовать "внесите пароль" или "введите пароль"?

Tags: выбор-слова

Какой вариант больше подходит для использования на страницах сайта?

Comment: А какой вариант нравится вам больше и почему вы думаете что второй подходит меньше?

Comment: В компьютерных системах давно уже устойчиво используется "ввести". "Внести" применимо к графам в бумажных формах.

Comment: внесите = contribute. Imagine "contribute password"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

“*Введите*” is correct. “*Внесите*”, to me personally, sounds
like a verb your would use when talking about money. E.g.:

> *Внесите необходимую сумму.*

Answer (score 0):

Ввести пароль

Слово "внести" означает "внести во внутрь что-либо" или "пополнить счёт"